# Divide similar users into social groups

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, cluster-analysis

[image]I have a dataset containing general consumer reviews of products purchased by users. The dataset also includes the item name, price, stars given by the consumer to the product. Please suggest me a way to approach this problem so as to make clusters of similar users using the given information. As of now I'm extracting keywords from the reviews column. I have shared the dataset preview.

Answer (score 1):

in my opinion you should try to use some text clustering methods. Probably, the most informative value in your dataset is a review part. So at first you could try to change representation of your input data (using e.q tokenization, word embeddings) and then use some clustering methods (DBSCAN, Kmeans, tsne) to show if there exist some distinction between these grousp.

Good starter should be:

https://www.kaggle.com/karthik3890/text-clustering

Comment: Kindly refrain from answering off-topic questions (like opinion-based ones), as advised in the community guidelines - please see [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions), [“Why shouldn't I answer off-topic questions?” FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262573/why-shouldnt-i-answer-off-topic-questions-faq), and [Should I answer off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133552/should-i-answer-off-topic-questions)

Comment: What did you find off-topic in my question? This guy just helped me. I think you should kindly refrain from commenting in such manner.